# $ af'(\xi)+bf'(\eta)=0 $ for some $ 0<\xi<\eta<1 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Suppose $ f(x) $ is a differentiable function defined on $ [0, 1] $, satisfying $ f(0)=f(1) $ and for every $ 0<a<b $, there exist $ 0<\xi<\eta<1 $ such that $ af'(\xi)+bf'(\eta)=0 $.

My attempt: WLOG, assume that $ f(0)=f(1)=0 $. If $ f'(x) $ has at least two zeros on $ (0, 1) $, then set $ f'(\xi)=f'(\eta)=0 $ and we are done. It leaves us to prove when $ f'(x) $ has exactly one zero on $ (0, 1) $. It should be clear that $ \xi $ and $ \eta $ will not be zeros of $ f'(x) $ on $ (0, 1) $ by our assumption. So it suffices to show that $$ \frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(\eta)}<-1 $$
for some $ \xi $ and $ \eta $. Then I am stuck......

---

**EDIT:**

It is pretty clear to see that $ \frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(\eta)}<0 $ for some $  0<\xi<\eta<1 $. Since $ f'(x) $ has only one zero on $ (0, 1) $, then WLOG, we assume that $ f(x)>0 $ when $ x\in (0, 1) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that by the mean value theorem, there exist $\displaystyle\xi\in \left(0,\frac{a}{a+b}\right)$ and $\displaystyle\eta\in\left(\frac{a}{a+b},1\right)$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{a+b}f'(\xi)&=f\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)-f(0)\\&=-f(1)+f\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)\\&=-\frac{b}{a+b}f'(\eta).
\end{align*}$$ It follows $0<\xi<\eta<1$ and $\displaystyle af'(\xi)+bf'(\eta)=0$. 
 Note: In fact, we don't need to assume $a<b$.

Comment: Nice! May I ask you how do you come with the idea of dividing $ (0, 1) $ by the point $ \frac{a}{a+b} $?

Comment: @user549397 At first, I started with the simplest case $a=b=1$, and observed that the we can apply MVT to three points $0,\frac 1 2$ and $1$ to find such $\xi$ and $\eta$.  It was a kind of intuition that if we get back to the original position after the unit time ($f(1)=f(0)$), then there must be two points of the time, $\xi$ in the first half way and $\eta$ in the second half way, such that their instantaneous velocity (i.e derivative of $f$) cancel each other. It turned out that this approach works, so I tried to generalize it to the general cases of $a,b$. I hope this will help :)

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you!!!